# LaTeX listings: different counters for different listing environments

Tags: latex, listings, caption

How do I create two lstlisting environments that each have its own counter?

If I use for example

```
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
    \lstset{ ... }
} {}

\lstnewenvironment{program}[2]{
    \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Program}
    \lstset{ ... }
} {}
```

And then

```
\begin{algorithm}{Algorithm caption}{alg-label}
...
\end{algorithm}

\begin{program}{Program caption}{prg-label}
...
\end{program}
```

Then they will share the counter, i.e. it will result for example in

```
Algorithm 1.1
    ...
Program 1.2
    ...
```

I would like the counting to be independent for different listing environments.

I also use the caption package to create a nice caption. I've already tried many things but none really successfuly. The only way that I found that indicates how to change the counter/file extension is via i.e. \DeclareCaptionType[fileext=alg]{algorithm} but the problem is that this command already defines a new environment so I don't know how to use it together with a new listings environment and the caption package. I'm using for example the following settings:

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}
```

Comment: You might have more luck asking your question on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcounter{algorithm}
\newcounter{program}

\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[2]{
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
  \let\c@lstlisting=\c@algorithm
  \let\thelstlisting=\thealgorithm
  \lstset{caption=#1}
} {}

\lstnewenvironment{program}[2]{
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Program}
  \let\c@lstlisting=\c@program
  \let\thelstlisting=\theprogram
  \lstset{caption=#1}
} {}
\makeatother
```